# Passing linked list as an array to CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda, linked-list

I am trying to transfer some data which is in the form of linked list to my GPGPU. Do I need to make as many transfers as there are number of nodes or is there a better and faster way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You may generate device vectors from iterator ranges when Thrust library is used. At the following site they provide an example for this case

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    // create an STL list with 4 values
    std::list<int> stl_list;

    stl_list.push_back(10);
    stl_list.push_back(20);
    stl_list.push_back(30);
    stl_list.push_back(40);

    // initialize a device_vector with the list
    thrust::device_vector<int> D(stl_list.begin(), stl_list.end());

    // copy a device_vector into an STL vector
    std::vector<int> stl_vector(D.size());
    thrust::copy(D.begin(), D.end(), stl_vector.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide

Take a look at the section with title "Iterators and Static Dispatching".

You may perform a similar operation with STL's algorithm library.

```
std::list<int> stl_list;
stl_list.push_back(10);
...
float *myarray = new float[stl_list.size()];
float *mydevicearray;
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&mydevicearray, sizeof(float)*stl_list.size()));
std::copy(stl_list.begin(), stl_list.end(), myarray);
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(myarray, mydevicearray, sizeof(float)*stl_list.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

These two examples should make the memcopy operation just once because copying memory to CUDA device is costly and it is not logical to do it for each element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are transferring the data from linked list to Array (to GPU), you can just send the values in the node to an Array (GPU). It is a simple one. You can use `cudaMalloc()` with the size of number of nodes.

If you are trying to transfer data from linked list to linked list (to GPU), it is a hectic process of creating nodes and transferring the data. You can invoke different functions for creating nodes, linking nodes and all. (not preferable as linked lists are more serial than parallel).

Its recommended to go for the first case. Its simple and all you want is data transfer.

Try [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust) library for data structures.